# Macrofusion in Linux will not load photos. Any ideas?

Tags: linux

As stated, I have Hugin, running Linux Mint and MAcrofusion will start the add photo process but nothing happens when I hit the add buttom.

Comment: Is this a recent problem? Or has it ever worked for you? Is this your first time using Macrofusion? I ask because this might a installation / configuration issue, in which case you might get more/better/faster answers at [unix.se]. On its face, this question isn't off-topic here, but if the problem is software install/config, Unix.SE is the best place for this.

Comment: First time to use/install.

Answer (score 2):

That is, because some of the libraries macro fusion depends on changed.

To fix it, open the python file `macrofusion.py`, go to line 621 and change `Image.fromstring(...` to `Image.frombytes(...`. If all the neccesary other libraries are correctly installed, it should work now.

Comment: No, still doesn't work.

I did learn to use the command line even though I would like this better I think.

Comment: What does it say in the command line though? What error messages do you get?

Comment: `/usr/bin/macrofusion` is the location of the file to patch.